# How to make call with the delete method with a requestbody

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have the following method:

```
   @Test
   public void correctHandleOrderDelete() throws JsonProcessingException
   {
      String uri = getUri();

      whenHttp(server)
         .match(delete(uri))
         .then(ok(),stringContent(mapper.writeValueAsString(response())),
               contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));

      OrderResponse response = orderRestClient.deleteOrder(ORDER_ID, deleteOrderDTO());

      assertThat(response.getOrderIdNumber()).isEqualTo(ORDER_ID_NUMBER);
      verifyHttp(server).once(
         method(DELETE),
         uri(uri)
      );
   }
```

The type of the variable `orderRestClient` is a class located in my api package. My other app will essentially have the api package as a dependency via maven in its pom.xml.
The `deleteOrder()` method pretty much uses `WebClient` to make the call to my controller.

The above test fails as it gives a 400 error as opposed to a 200. For sanity purposes, I changed the HTTP method from delete to post, made my controller accept a POST request and then it worked. So after some digging, I came across that having a requestbody for a delete method does go against convention.

Is there anyway of making this test pass whilst providing a request body and a delete method?

Comment: Why do you have the need of sending a request body in a DELETE action?

Comment: @JoãoDias I need more metadeta for the entity im deleting. The ID wont be sufficient.